# Jquery modal window help

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
All,
```

I need to get the below code (radio buttons,input boxes,textarea) on a jquery modal window.

The requirements are that the contents should be enlarged on opening a dialog window when clicked on (Open window) hyperlink.Else be small in size.

Please help me out with it.

PS:I had posted the same question in another post (i have formatted the code in this)

Thanks.....

//($("#modal").dialog('open');)

```
<body background="my.jpg" size="100%" style="overflow-y:auto;">
<form name="shipinfo" action="main.php" method="post">
<div id="pics">
<table width="100%">
<input type="image"src="PHOTO-SHOP/PHOTO-SHOP/N.gif"/>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="type" id="type" VALUE="type1">Type1</input>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="type" id="type" VALUE="type2">Type2</input>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="type" id="type" VALUE="type3">Type3</input>
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="type" id="type" VALUE="type4" >Type4</input>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<?php
if($programtype == 'Type1')
{
?>
<tr>
<td>
*Enter new type <input type="text" name="javaname" value="<?php echo $params?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td>
Flag:<input type="text" name="parameters" value="<?php echo $flag?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br> <br>
<table width="100%">
<tr width="10%"><td>
<a href="" id="a" >Open window</a>
<TEXTAREA name="comment" id="comment" rows="15" cols="65" onscroll="sync();"spellcheck="false"><?php echo $comment ?></TEXTAREA>
</td>
<td>
<TEXTAREA Name="mail" id="mail" rows="15" cols="65"  spellcheck="false"><?php
if($mail == true)
{
}
if($type == 'type1' || $type == '2')
{
}
?>
</TEXTAREA>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<tr width="90%"><td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="statcheck('1')"/>
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">
<input type="hidden" name="Action">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to do things like this I used [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/).